# How can I import wasm file in VS Code Extension?

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, webassembly

I'm working on VS Code Extension with a library which use .wasm like below.

```js
import { Func } from "npm-lib"
import Runtime from "npm-lib/bin.wasm"

Func(Runtime, otherArgs) // execute
```

and I bundle it with webpack and file-loader like below.

```js
{
  test:/\.wasm$/i,
  loader: 'file-loader',
  options: {
    name: '[name].[ext]',
  }
}
```

and output in dist directory is like below.
`bin.wasm` is exist in dist dir.

```
dist
  extension.js
  extension.LISENCE.txt
  extension.js.map
  bin.wasm
```

However, This cause error `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'bin.wasm'`.

How can I use such a wasm library in VS Code Extension?
(this is work file in ordinary website's program)

Comment: See my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72600840/load-wasm-in-vscode-web-extension/73550065#73550065